# Angular2-Dart : Component Template not loading

Tags: angular, angular-dart

### Context

**I'm trying to build a menu component for angular2 dart.**
Here is a screenshot: 
[Menu screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdtTu.png)
-> more on the crappy formatting of menu items after "Problem" heading below

I have an AppComponent for preview, as angular2 style suggests. This is called  and is the bootstrap component.

The AppComponent template contains the code for my menu components as displayed below:

```
<jb-menu [activeBreakpoints]="activeBreakpoints"
     [collapsedStateBreakpoints]="collapsedStateBreakpoints"
     customCssPath="css/jbMenuStyles.css"
     #menu>

    <jb-menu-item *ngFor="let url of urls; let i=index"
              customCssPath="css/jbMenuItemStyles.css"
              [openInNewTab]="true"
              [disableNavigation]="true"
              [collapsedMode]="menu.isCollapsible"
              [url]="url"
              [active]="isActiveUrl(url)"
              [textContent]="menuItems[url]"
              (click)="onClick(url)">
    </jb-menu-item>
</jb-menu>
```

Both menu components (JbMenu and JbMenuItem) are registered in AppComponent: `directives: const [JbMenu, JbMenuItem])`

I have some logging inside both components to test proper initialization, which is shown below.

```
2016.43.17 08:43:25.124 jb_menu.jb_menu_item    
[INFO]: JbMenuItem constructor: 802477160 VM645:1 

2016.43.17 08:43:25.132 jb_menu.jb_menu_item    
[INFO]: JbMenuItem constructor: 785692334 VM645:1 

2016.43.17 08:43:25.133 jb_menu.jb_menu_item    
[INFO]: JbMenuItem constructor: 930402410 VM645:1 

2016.43.17 08:43:25.168 jb_menu.jb_menu_item    
[FINEST]:        hash: 802477160,
    url: http://www.w3schools.com/,
    customCssPath: css/jbMenuItemStyles.css,
    active: true,
    collapsedMode: false,
    isMenuButton: null,
    openInNewTab: true,
    disableNavigation: true 
 VM645:1 

2016.43.17 08:43:25.171 jb_menu.jb_menu_item    
[FINEST]:           hash: 785692334,
    url: http://www.apple.com/de/,
    customCssPath: css/jbMenuItemStyles.css,
    active: false,
    collapsedMode: false,
    isMenuButton: null,
    openInNewTab: true,
    disableNavigation: true
VM645:1 

2016.43.17 08:43:25.172 jb_menu.jb_menu_item    
[FINEST]:           hash: 930402410,
    url: http://www.chip.de/#,
    customCssPath: css/jbMenuItemStyles.css,
    active: false,
    collapsedMode: false,
    isMenuButton: null,
    openInNewTab: true,
    disableNavigation: true
VM645:1 

2016.43.17 08:43:25.180 jb_menu.jb_menu_component   
[FINEST]:           customCssPath: css/jbMenuStyles.css,
    collapsedStateBreakpoints: [small, medium, large],
    _operationMode: responsive,
    labelCollapsed = Menü,
    isOpen: true,
    isCollapsible: true
```

### Problem

The console log tells me, that both JbMenu and JbMenuItem are initialized as intended. But for some reason **the template of JbMenuItem was not loaded**. 
This could be seen also in the screenshot at the top of this post, as no styles where applied to menu items

```
<jb-menu _ngcontent-mae-1="" customcsspath="css/jbMenuStyles.css" _nghost-mae-3=""><link _ngcontent-mae-3="" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jbMenuStyles.css">

    <nav _ngcontent-mae-3="" class="">
    <!--template bindings={}-->
    <!--template bindings={}-->
    <!--template bindings={}-->
    <jb-menu-item _ngcontent-mae-1=""
                  customcsspath="css/jbMenuItemStyles.css" 
                  _nghost-mae-4=""> W3C Schools </jb-menu-item>
    <jb-menu-item _ngcontent-mae-1=""
                  customcsspath="css/jbMenuItemStyles.css" 
                  _nghost-mae-4="">Apple</jb-menu-item>
    <jb-menu-item _ngcontent-mae-1=""
                  customcsspath="css/jbMenuItemStyles.css" 
                  _nghost-mae-4="">Chip</jb-menu-item>
    </nav>
</jb-menu>
```

Each JbMenuItem component should contain this template:

```
<!--External stylesheet which can be passed from the user to 
    incorporate outside styles for the inside template.
    CSS-Variables are not useful for now ;)-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" [href]="safeCustomCssUrl">

<a [href]="url" 
   [class.active]="active
   [class.collapsed]="collapsedMode" 
   (click)="onClick($event)"
   [target]="target">
   <!--this will transclude the button content though this component-->
   <ng-content></ng-content>
</a>
```

Does anybody have a good idea how to solve this?

Thanks in advance! :)﻿

Comment: Can you please post the code of the two components and the template of `<jb-menu>`?

Comment: The code repo can be found here: 

[Repo Link](https://bitbucket.org/jbwebsoft/jb_menu/src/3466e3ee9ae0bbff268942663be27d98d5d68e34/?at=angular2)

;

[jbMenuComponent](https://bitbucket.org/jbwebsoft/jb_menu/src/3466e3ee9ae0bbff268942663be27d98d5d68e34/lib/src/menu/?at=angular2)

;

[jbMenuItemComponent](https://bitbucket.org/jbwebsoft/jb_menu/src/3466e3ee9ae0bbff268942663be27d98d5d68e34/lib/src/item/?at=angular2)

Comment: Sorry, but that's just too much code. You should strip it down to the absolute minimum that still allows to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Ah, i thought you want access to the actual repository. I will make a stripped down version of it ;)

Comment: No, it's way too hard to understand other peoples code. The less the easier.

Comment: Ok, I'll found the answer myself while creating the stripped down version of the problem! :D I'll write an answer to the question right after. 

Thanks for helping! :)

Comment: That's not uncommon that creating a stripped down version reveals the problem. This is one of the reasons it is usually requested ;-)

Comment: Yes, that's right. I will do that the next time before asking. But now it's documented on SO, so maybe it can help other people. ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I found the answer myself.

The Problem was the binding of [textContent] inside jb-menu-item tag inside AppComponent Template.

```dart
<jb-menu-item *ngFor="let url of urls; let i=index"
              ...
              [textContent]="menuItems[url]">
</jb-menu-item>
```

This disables **ANY** rendering of subcomponents inside jb-menu-item tag!

### Solution

Bind the text content of jb-menu-item with normal curly braces binding to jb-menu-item tag and remove the binding to textContent.

```dart
<jb-menu-item *ngFor="let url of urls; let i=index">
    {{menuItems[url]}}
</jb-menu-item>
```

### Deeper Background:

There was a ng-bind directive in angular-dart to bind something to the content of a tag without using double curly braces inside the tag and ng-cloak.
I thought, i could use that too in angular2-dart, but instead of binding with ng-bind attribute (which doesn't exists anymore), I thought I can bind directly to the [textContent] property, which proved to be wrong.